# Как реализовать смену цвета текста при активном блоке старой цены?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Помогите написать скрипт желательно в jQuery, при условии, если над блоком основной цены существует блок старой цены, что бы цвет основной цены менялся на красный, как в коде. Иначе пусть будет черным. В js и jQuery пока только обучаюсь, а скрипт уже нужен

```css
.cart__price-old {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #9E9E9E;
}
.cart__price-main{
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #DF5151;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart__price">
    <p class="cart__price-old price">9600</p>
    <p class="cart__price-main price">5960</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не удержался :) Решение на чистом CSS:

```css
.cart__price-old {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #9E9E9E;
}
.cart__price-main {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #DF5151;
}

.cart__price {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cart__price-old + .cart__price-main {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart__price">
    <p class="cart__price-old price">9600</p>
    <p class="cart__price-main price">5960</p>
</div>

<div class="cart__price">
    <p class="cart__price-main price">5960</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Черт возьми, это гениально! Спасибо!

Comment: @MichaelKardamon Если ответ вам помог, то пожалуйста примите его - отметье зелёную галочку слева от ответа

Answer (score -1):

Это можно сделать и с помощью `css`

```css
.cart__price-old {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #9E9E9E;
}

.cart__price-main {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #DF5151;
}

.cart__price-old ~ .cart__price-main {
  color: lime
}
```

```html
<div class="cart__price">
  <p class="cart__price-old price">9600</p>
  <p class="cart__price-main price">5960</p>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="cart__price">
  <p class="cart__price-main price">3000</p>
</div>
```

---

---

А если нужно именно на `JS`, то вот код для вашей ситуации:

```
const price_box_list = document.querySelectorAll('.cart__price')

price_box_list.forEach((el) => {
  const old_price = el.querySelector('.cart__price-old')
  
  if (old_price) {
    const mainPrice = el.querySelector('.cart__price-main')
    mainPrice.style.color = 'aqua'
  }
})
```

Comment: При решении с JS вы смотрите на существование блока `price-old`, а не то что он находится ДО `price-main`

Comment: @EzioMercer Цитирую отрывок из условия задачи:  ```при условии, если над блоком основной цены существует блок старой цены```.   Тем более, если код сильно поменяется внутри  
 ```.cart__price```, моё решение JS  останется рабочим (если классы останутся прежними)

Comment: И где вы проверяете "над блоком"? Как по мне вы просто смотрите на наличие блока старой цены :)

Comment: А зачем писать лишние проверки, удлиняя код, и делая его менее универсальным? Абсолютно ненужное занятие ни в рамках этой задачи, ни в реальном проекте.

Comment: О практичности я и не говорил. Я лишь сказал, что код не делает то что надо в задаче :)

Comment: Это даже смешно читать) Код выполняет поставленную задачу на 100%, а ваше субъективное мнение выглядит как попытка придумать проблему на ровном месте. Не намерен дальше продолжать эту дискуссию, тк никакой пользы от неё не вижу. Оставляю вас наедине с вашими мыслями, и да прибудет с вами сила )

Comment: "А зачем писать лишние проверки" - на самом деле этого и не нужно вам делать. А замечание верное, *наличие блока* и *наличие блока в определённом месте* - это не одно и то же

Comment: @HaZcker не очень понимаю вас... Вроде бы проверку на nextElementSibling не так уж сложно написать...

Comment: А я не понимаю логику пользователей на этом сайте. Я дал 2 варианта, один на ```css```, другой на ```js```. Оба варианта являются рабочим ответом на вопрос. И я дал ответ раньше чем EzioMercer. Но тем не мене, мне ставят дизлайк. Странный народ.